# I need help to install Skype on Kali 2020

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, skype

I wasn't lucky with all of the Google help so I came here. I installed the latest version of Skype on my Kali 2020 with **sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb**, and it all went correctly and installed with no errors whatsoever. However, no matter how many times I press the Skype icon, it launches (just the loading bar) and then it disappears. Does somebody have any assumptions of what is wrong with my Skype? I would really appreciate help. Thank You anyway.

Comment: See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). TLDR: kali isn't a general purpose OS, don't use it unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Can you run Skype from the terminal and post the output? Add to your question, please.

Comment: No I can't run it from terminal. When I enter skypeforlinux, it seems to process the command but nothing launched.

Answer (score 0):

For just the purpose of installing Skype in Kali OS :

- Install Snapd via [this](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-kali) process.
- Install Skype by `sudo snap install skype --classic`

Installing via snap will ensure regular updates and modularity of packages. Besides Snap has a ton of other packages that you may need.

As for uninstalling the dpkg install, follow [this tutorial.](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/install-remove-deb-package/)

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Hey, I installed using snapd, but how do I launch it?

Comment: If you have enabled snapd.apparmor via systemctl, then all you need to do is the sudo snap install .... command. Snap is a commandline package manager like apt. It has no gui.

Comment: Try 'snap help --all' and if it works, just type 'snap install skype --classic''

Comment: @Vuk Stamenkovic, such questions are really quickly resolved in r/linux subreddit. Try posting your error in reddit, if any.